# rebooting a sharded mongodb cluster

Tags: mongodb, cluster-computing

What is the process to reboot a MongoDB cluster? The MongoDB cluster should be restarted without primaries changing to secondaries because the replicas think that a failure is happening?

Comment: why do you need to reboot the "cluster"?  Rebooting is usually associated with a single machine or process.

Comment: Several use cases. For example, you want to change a configuration across the cluster and want to write an script to restart all the mongod processes but you do not want to manage the sequence manually. Is that clear?

Comment: if you want no failover, shut down the secondaries first.  Primary will become a secondary, then you restart it, then start secondaries.